# The Frame of Reference of Light

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light

According to my current understanding of special relativity, light would not 'see' the universe's time tick. In other words, the universe would remain a snapshot in time according to a photon from the instant the photon was created. Is that true? Also, would a photon 'see' ordinary (moving slowly) objects move at the speed of light? If not, then at what speed?